# Problems with QWidget delete and clean up memory used

Tags: qt, memory-management, memory-leaks, qwidget

Well, i'm a begginer with Qt development and i have a big problem. My project works with embedded Qt at Linux and for this i have care with used memory. Ok!

In my code i have a stack with QWidgets than i'm showing. That stack has a pointer to my QWidgets. Before, i just hide my QWidgets and memory was wasted , i had done that to open fast my QWidgets. Right now, i'm deleting the QWidgets and instace them always than necessary.

My problem is, for example, when i run my project the memory used is 21%, ok. When i open the first menu, the memory goes to 23% used. But when i close it, the memory goes to 21% used. My ask is: Where is the another 1% used? Is strange because if i open again the menu, will be used just 1%.

Seems Qt  store something in cache to show ui after.

I saw some topics about my problem, and people always say about Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose or deletelater() signal. I tried use those solutions, but didn't work with me.

Someone can help me? I don't understand whats happening...

Comment: Sorry, i didn't say but now, when i close some QWidget i delete it using: delete myQWidget;

Comment: do you mean 21% -open menu-> 23% -close menu-> 22%?

Comment: Yes @buster. In this example i opened just one QWidget, right? But in my application is possible to open many QWidgets children of the first menu. If i to open many QWidgets and after close them, the percentual goes to 27% or more.

Comment: Well, i didn't about this... But i saw in this link: http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-29400.html than my problem in fact can not be really a problem. Maybe my OS is managing the memory and the 1% can be some library or anything than i can be use later.

For this, maybe my OS doesn't clean totally the memory. Well, i will do some tests and if to conclude something i will post here again.

Thanks!

P.S: sorry, my english is not so good...

Comment: How did you track the memory usage?

Comment: Well, i don't have specific techniques to track... I'm just careful with pointers for example, trying delete them when possible, and i use the Qt management memory making QWidgets with parent, so Qt deletes all children of the my QWidget deleted.

Comment: Not my point. You give us these percentages. If that comes from a process monitor or something similar, keep in mind that these are not good debugging tools and don't necessarily provide any indication of memory leaks or the like.

Comment: Oh, sorry... Well, i saw that percentage using 'top' command in the terminal, there i saw the used memory by my software. I'm not really using any debugging tools for this.